# How can I gather state information from a set of actors using only the actorSystem?

Tags: scala, akka

I'm creating an actor system, which has a list of actors representing some kind of session state.
These session are created by a factory actor (which might, in the future, get replaced by a router, if performance requires that - this should be transparent to the rest of the system, however).
Now I want to implement an operation where I get some state information from each of my currently existing session actors.
I have no explicit session list, as I want to rely on the actor system "owning" the sessions. I tried to use the actor system to look up the current session actors. The problem is that I did not find a "get all actor refs with this naming pattern" method. I tried to use the "/" operator on the system, followed by resolveOne - but got lost in a maze of future types.

The basic idea I had was:
- Send a message to all current session actors (as given to my by my ActorSystem).
- Wait for a response from them (preferably by using just the "ask" pattern - the method calling this broadcaster request/response is just a monitoring resp. debugging method, so blocking is no probleme here.
- And then collect the responses into a result.

After a death match against Scala's type system I had to give up for now.
Is there really no way of doing something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, then I can offer up a couple of ways you can accomplish this (though there are certainly others).

**Option 1**

In this approach, there will be an actor that is responsible for waking up periodically and sending a request to all session actors to get their current stats.  That actor will use `ActorSelection` with a wildcard to accomplish that goal.  A rough outline if the code for this approach is as follows:

```
case class SessionStats(foo:Int, bar:Int)
case object GetSessionStats

class SessionActor extends Actor{
  def receive = {
    case GetSessionStats =>
      println(s"${self.path} received a request to get stats")
      sender ! SessionStats(1, 2)
  }
}


case object GatherStats
class SessionStatsGatherer extends Actor{
  context.system.scheduler.schedule(5 seconds, 5 seconds, self, GatherStats)(context.dispatcher)

  def receive = {
    case GatherStats =>
      println("Waking up to gether stats")
      val sel = context.system.actorSelection("/user/session*")
      sel ! GetSessionStats

    case SessionStats(f, b) =>
      println(s"got session stats from ${sender.path}, values are $f and $b")
  }
}
```

Then you could test this code with the following:

```
val system = ActorSystem("test")
system.actorOf(Props[SessionActor], "session-1")
system.actorOf(Props[SessionActor], "session-2")

system.actorOf(Props[SessionStatsGatherer])

Thread.sleep(10000)
system.actorOf(Props[SessionActor], "session-3")
```

So with this approach, as long as we use a naming convention, we can use an actor selection with a wildcard to always find all of the session actors even though they are constantly coming (starting) and going (stopping).

**Option 2**

A somewhat similar approach, but in this one, we use a centralized actor to spawn the session actors and act as a supervisor to them.  This central actor also contains the logic to periodically poll for stats, but since it's the parent, it does not need an `ActorSelection` and can instead just use its `children` list.  That would look like this:

```
case object SpawnSession
class SessionsManager extends Actor{
  context.system.scheduler.schedule(5 seconds, 5 seconds, self, GatherStats)(context.dispatcher)
  var sessionCount = 1

  def receive = {
    case SpawnSession =>
      val session = context.actorOf(Props[SessionActor], s"session-$sessionCount")
      println(s"Spawned session: ${session.path}")
      sessionCount += 1
      sender ! session

    case GatherStats =>
      println("Waking up to get session stats")
      context.children foreach (_ ! GetSessionStats)

    case SessionStats(f, b) =>
      println(s"got session stats from ${sender.path}, values are $f and $b")      
  }
}
```

And could be tested as follows:

```
val system = ActorSystem("test")
val manager = system.actorOf(Props[SessionsManager], "manager")
manager ! SpawnSession
manager ! SpawnSession
Thread.sleep(10000)
manager ! SpawnSession
```

Now, these examples are extremely trivialized, but hopefully they paint a picture for how you could go about solving this issue with either `ActorSelection` or a management/supervision dynamic.  And a bonus is that `ask` is not needed in either and also no blocking.

Comment: I think Option 2 is better IMO because it doesn't depend on the names of the actors (which are not typed). Having a central actor spawn all session actors is a better approach. The only time this may not work (at least directly) is when you have multiple actor systems (i.e., a cluster). But you can easily extend it to support that use case as well.

Comment: It depends how you want to couple your sessions. If it makes sense for users to own session and the user Actor be the parent of a session then I would go with option 1. It is less typesafe but also non-intrusive if the session stats gathering is needed for non-functional/cross-cutting concerns.

Answer (score 1):

There have been many additional changes in this project, so my answer/comments have been delayed quite a bit :-/

First, the session stats gathering should not be periodical, but on request. My original idea was to "mis-use" the actor system as my map of all existing session actors, so that I would not need a supervisor actor knowing all sessions.

This goal has shown to be elusive - session actors depend on shared state, so the session creator must watch sessions anyways.

This makes Option 2 the obvious answer here - the session creator has to watch all children anyways.

The most vexing hurdle with option 1 was "how to determine when all (current) answers are there" - I wanted the statistics request to take a snapshot of all currently existing actor names, query them, ignore failures (if a session dies before it can be queried, it can be ignored here) - the statistics request is only a debugging tool, i.e. something like a "best effort".
The actor selection api tangled me up in a thicket of futures (I am a Scala/Akka newbie), so I gave up on this route.

Option 2 is therefore better suited to my needs.